# Asciidoctor tables in docx no style

Tags: pandoc, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I create a asciidoc documentation with asciidocFx and rendering looks ok.
When i convert the asciidoc to xml and xml to docx, i see in my docx that tables are no borders and i would like to know what ?
adoc

[%header,cols=4*]
|===
|
^|a
^|b
^|x

|d
|e
|f
|

|g
|h
|i
|

|j
|k
|l
|

|===

The commands that i used
asciidoctor --backend docbook -a data-uri file1.adoc
and
pandoc --from docbook file.xml --to docx --output file1.docx

I expected the table to have borders